# Problem with Pub/Sub notifications acknowledge

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm new to Google Cloud and I'm trying to implement a subscription to a theme on Pub/Sub that sends a notification upon recieving an email on my gmail account inbox. I already did the configuration on the Google Cloud side, and setted it up as push delivery, and as the documentation says:

All notifications need to be acknowledged. If you use webhook push delivery, then responding successfully (e.g. HTTP 200) will acknowledge the notification. (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

But instead, when i recieve a notification and I return HTTP 200, it doesn't confirm the PubSub message and it gets sent again to my endpoint multiple times, so instead of answering once any incoming emails, it answers multiple times. Any idea on how to fix it? Thanks for your help.
Here's the code:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Notification")]
public class NotificationController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost(Name = "Notification")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Notify([FromBody] PubsubMessage message)
    {
        GmailAPI gmailApi = new GmailAPI();

    string textContent = GmailAPI.DecodeBase64UrlString(message.message.data);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textContent))
    {
        PubSubBody info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PubSubBody>(textContent);

        if (info != null)
        {
            string messageId = gmailApi.GetMessageIdFromHistory(info.historyId);
            Console.WriteLine(messageId);


            Console.WriteLine(messageId);
            Message messageInfo = gmailApi.GetMessage(messageId);
            string senderEmail = gmailApi.GetSenderEmail(messageInfo);

            string msgContent = gmailApi.GetMessageContent(messageId);

            MimeMessage msg = gmailApi.createEmail(senderEmail, "*****@gmail.com",
                "Response", msgContent);

            Console.WriteLine(msgContent);
            gmailApi.sendEmail(gmailApi.createMessageWithEmail(msg));
        }
    }

    return Ok(new { message = "Notificación recibida correctamente." });
}
}
```

Tried answering an email with the same body content once, but ended up answering it multiple times. I guess it's because pub/sub notifications don't get confirmed and it gets resent.

Comment: PubSUb default timeout is 10s. Did you try to increase the timeout of your subscription?